# How do I modify the search index in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, search

I'm loving (parts) of this new Unity interface; in particular the searching with the windows key (just like Windows 7!).

But how do I:

1. Tell it what programs I'd like to be able to return
2. Tell it where I'd like file searches to be performed

I presume 2 has something to do with indexing, but I do not know the indexing backend, and the "official" documentation is pretty useless for a power user (vs a l33t user that contributes patches ;))

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no control over this atm (atleast in 11.04). It searches through all the regular menu entries /usr/share/menu IIRC.
2. I'm unsure as to if it does index. I'm pretty sure it only searches through ~/ (your home directory).

And I agree, the documentation is pretty craptastic.

Answer (score 0):

This might be closer to what you were looking for I guess unity uses Lenses for searching. You should be able to create a lens and have it search either locally or remotely.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses#Overview

also just found this 
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/awesome-unity-lenses-ubuntu/

Comment: Please include a summary of the linked content as well, or post your answer as a comment.  Answers are expected to be relatively self-contained, more than just links.